# Fake PR of a website

Tags: pagerank

I just saw a website, its PR 10. Now this is impossible as the websites quality is nowhere near PR 10. I know that one can change to PR to show 10 if he redirects the site but in this case, its not getting redirected anywhere. I am pretty sure something is wrong with it. Please help me out.

The domain is `www.virginia11.info`

Comment: How are you checking PageRank?

Comment: Wow, the Holy Grail! ;) The "SearchStatus" browser extension for Firefox also returns PR 10 for that URL. Does anyone have the Google toolbar installed with the PR tool enabled? However, I do smell something funny. All other (indexed) pages on that site that I've tried return "unranked". Does anyone really know the internal PR that Google uses?

Comment: @danlefree: I use an addon but I am not the only one who sees the same PR.

Comment: Interesting to note that almost 1 year on and this site doesn't exist anymore, there is nothing indexed by Google and the corresponding PR is _null_. So, _something_ went wrong it would seem!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few explanations for the mismatch of PR and site quality; and some are black-hat SEO techniques. Normally when this happens, it's because of some kind of large

---

First, **a server redirect** for search bots to go to a different site (Probably much higher quality).

Second, PR takes a while to impact. The site could have **degraded significantly in the past few weeks** due to a change in management, domain sale, etc.

Third, the PR resource you looked at **might not be 100% accurate** (or a paid site).

And fourth, only for objectivity, your perception of a 'high quality' site **isn't the same as what Google or Yahoo or Bing! thinks**.

***TL;DR***
There are many explanations for this kind of behavior, some are blackhat, others are just mistakes.